# Как сделать, чтобы сервис работал при выключенном экране?

Tags: android, background-task

У меня есть сервис, выполняющий запросы в сеть с интервалом в минуту. Мне сказали запускать его при включении устройства. Это я сделал. Теперь надо его сделать работающим в режиме ожидания и я не могу ничего понять, даже документацию. Везде пишут про получение `WakeLock` и вызова `acquire`, но не пишут куда его писать.

Еще раз: сервис должен запуститься единожды как при включении устройства, так и при запуске приложения. А если устройство включится и пользователь откроет приложение? Запустится два сервиса?

Мой `BroadCastReceiver`

```
public class BootReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationsService.class);
        startWakefulService(context, serviceIntent);
    }
}
}
```

Сервис

```
public class NotificationsService extends IntentService
{
    //блабла
public NotificationsService(){
    super("NotificationService");
}

    public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");
    pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    configEditor = pref.edit();
}

    @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onStartCommand");
    new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            connectWithIntervale();
        }
    }.start();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

    public void connectWithIntervale(){
        try { TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1) } catch(Exception ignored) {}
        //запрос в сеть
     }

   @Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "NotificationWL");
    wakeLock.acquire();
    BootReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

Запускаю сервис из активности так

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, NotificationsService.class);
startService(i);
```

Что надо еще сделать? Или это все? Я что-то ничего не понимаю, ресивер же запустит сервис при включении, а активность тогда что сделает?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изобретение велосипедов с `WakeLock` крайне не рекомендуется, т.к. сводит работу Doze Mode на нет, сжирает батарею и вообще плохо. Для периодических задач в  фоне используйте [`Firebase Job Dispatcher`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android), либо [evernote/android-job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job). Если Вам нужно получить новые данные с сервера, то пользуйтесь [`FCM`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/), это намного более оптимизированное решение.

---

Примерный код для `Firebase Job Dispatcher`, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37720015/firebase-jobdispatcher-how-does-it-work-compared-to-previous-apis-jobschedule) дополнительный FAQ по нему.

В `BootReceiver` и `onCreate` в `MainActivity`:

```
    FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));
    Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            // the JobService that will be called
            .setService(MyJobService.class)
            // uniquely identifies the job
            .setTag("request")
            // recurring job
            .setRecurring(true)
            // run even after reboot
            .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
            // start between 0 and 60 seconds from now
            .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 60))
            // don't overwrite an existing job with the same tag
            .setReplaceCurrent(false)
            // retry with exponential backoff
            .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
            // run on an any network
            .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK) 
            .build();

    dispatcher.schedule(myJob);
```

Пример `MyJobService` можно посмотреть в документации `Job Dispatcher`, в нём выполняется сам запрос в сеть, не забудьте зарегистрировать его в манифесте.

Такой `Job` будет примерно гарантировать примерно раз в минуту запрос. Повторюсь, что это **слишком** часто и это **плохой** подход, лучше воспользоваться `FCM`. Про ограничения Doze Mode можно почитать [здесь](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html).

Comment: Не совсем понял. Сервис, ресивер, где что писать? `Firebase Job Dispatcher` будет работать когда экран выключен?

Comment: @Flippy, обновил ответ

Comment: Попробовал я вообщем FirebaseJobDispatcher + Volley для запросов. Когда экран выключен, уведомления не приходят. Либа не подходит?

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы в режиме ожидания сервис тоже работал

Comment: а что вы думаете по поводу чистого JobService

Comment: @MartinezToni Вы про что именно спрашиваете? В целом, ответу уже больше 2 лет, сейчас уже лучше сразу использовать WorkManager

Comment: Использую Worker manager, но на miui не работает когда приложении закрыто и включена периодичность. На остальных устройствах все хорошо, вот ищу почему так?

Comment: @MartinezToni Потому что miui - прошивка качества "Китай" в плохом смысле этого слова. Она может вести себя далеко не по спецификации и корректного поведения от неё ждать не стоит

Answer (score 1):

Ваша задача создать расписание для запуска вашего сервиса. При включении устройства (т.е. ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) или при запуске Activity вызываете:

```
void setUpSchedule(Context context){
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, BootReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(START_NETWORK_UPDATES);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        new Date().getTime(), // с текущего момента
        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1), // раз в минуту
        alarmIntent);
}
```

В BootReceiver срабатывает расписание, ресивер для вас создает лок (вам его создавать не нужно) и будет держать пока вы ему не скажете, что работа закончена, запускаете сервис:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (START_NETWORK_UPDATES.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationsService.class);
        startWakefulService(context, serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

В NotificationsService обрабатываете запуск из ресивера, как закончите, сообщите, ресивер сам отпустит лок:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
{
    connectWithIntervale(); // синхронная операция
    BootReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

ЗЫ onStartCommand в сервисе не нужен и стартовать сервис как обычный тоже нет нужды. Достаточно работы по расписанию.
ЗЗЫ Соглашусь с комментарием по поводу того, что раз в минуту будить телефон, плохая практика. С другой стороны, пуши могут задерживаться или вообще теряться. Следует искать золотую середину (м.б. 5 минут, а может и раз в час будет достаточно), исходя из задачи.

Comment: Интервал в минуту это требование а не моя выходка :) я уже почти доделал связку Firebase + Volley